# Consulta entre intervalo de datas?

Tags: sql-server

## Tabela `Ciclos`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tenho a data **2018-07-05**

Como eu poderia montar uma *query* entre os intervalos de `CiDtIni` e `CiDtFim` de acordo com a data acima?

Comment: `select * from Ciclos where dataInformada  between CiDtFim AND  dataInformada`

Comment: select * from Ciclos where dataInformada between ciDtIni and CiDtFim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu tinha informado uma consulta na aba de comentários que creio ser o que necessita. Basta utilizar o `BETWEEN` para trabalhar com range de datas.

```
SELECT *
FROM Ciclos
WHERE dataInformada BETWEEN CiDtIni AND CiDtFim
```

Comment: No comentário você postou `select * from Ciclos where dataInformada between CiDtFim AND dataInformada`, não está errado? Eu estava tentando entender, e agora que você postou diferente, essa sim entendi.

Comment: @RBZ no comentário foi erro de digitação!

Comment: Entendi! Pior é que tem 3 votos o comentário. Dá para ver a atenção dos que votaram! rs